# Python sort dictionary by value in descending order then sort subgroups in ascending order?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sample dict:

`{'zed': 3, 'revenge': 3, 'laila': 3, 'bubo': 3, 'adele': 3, 'robert': 2, 'gia': 2, 'cony': 2, 'bandit': 2, 'anita': 2}`

I want to sort these players by their score in descending order, so the scores with 3 goes first. But if there are more players with the same score, they should be arranged alphabetically, so the result should look like this:

`{'adele': 3, 'bubo': 3, 'laila': 3, 'revenge': 3, 'zed': 3, 'anita': 2, 'bandit': 2, 'cony': 2, 'gia': 2, 'robert': 2}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) along with [`dict.items`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items):

```
d = {'zed': 3, 'revenge': 3, 'laila': 3, 'bubo': 3, 'adele': 3, 'robert': 2, 'gia': 2, 'cony': 2, 'bandit': 2, 'anita': 2}
sorted_d = dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda kvp: (-kvp[1], kvp[0])))
print(sorted_d)
```

**Output:**

```
{'adele': 3, 'bubo': 3, 'laila': 3, 'revenge': 3, 'zed': 3, 'anita': 2, 'bandit': 2, 'cony': 2, 'gia': 2, 'robert': 2}
```